# How to validate current, new, and new password confirmation in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created the password route, view and method in `UserController@getProfilePassword` and `UserController@postProfilePassword`

At the moment, if I fill out the `new_password` field, it gets hashed and submitted to the database correctly, then I can login with the new password.

But I need to be able to validate the `new_password` and `new_password_confirm` to make sure they're the same and validate the user's current password as well.

How can I do that?

EDIT: I added `$this->validate` to the method, but now I keep getting the error `The password confirmation confirmation does not match.` even though they do match as I am using a simple password. Also I think I need to check against the current password manually as `validator` won't do it for me.

```
public function getProfilePassword(Request $request) {
    return view('profile/password', ['user' => Auth::user()]);
}

public function postProfilePassword(Request $request) {
    $user = Auth::user();

    $this->validate($request, [
        'old_password'          => 'required',
        'password'              => 'required|min:4',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|confirmed'
    ]);

    $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('new_password'));
    $user->save();
}
```

And this is the view

```
<form action="{{ route('profile/updatepassword') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Current Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="old_password" class="form-control" id="old_password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">New Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control" id="password_confirmation">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Change Password</button>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There's a `Hash::check()` function which allows you to check whether the old password entered by user is correct or not.

`usage`

```
if (Hash::check("param1", "param2")) {
 //add logic here
}

param1 - user password that has been entered on the form
param2 - old password hash stored in database
```

it will return true if old password has been entered correctly and you can add your logic accordingly

for `new_password` and `new_confirm_password` to be same, you can add your validation in form request like

```
'new_password' => 'required',
'new_confirm_password' => 'required|same:new_password'
```

Comment: Thank you for these useful tips. I was using `confirmation` instead of `same:new_password` - just changed it and it worked. And I'll be using the `Hash::check()` to validate the current password.

Comment: glad that it helped :)

Comment: Another good trick to use in the confirmation field: the `confirmed` validation rule <[link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-confirmed)>.

Your actual rule would be just one line, like this:
`'new_password' => 'required|confirmed'`. And the confirmation field name should be `new_password_confirmation`.

Answer (score 33):

> If you only need the functionality of a custom rule once throughout your application, you may use a Closure instead of a rule object. The Closure receives the attribute's name, the attribute's value, and a $fail callback that should be called if validation fails

```
$request->validate([
    'new_password' => 'required|confirmed|min:4',
    'current_password' => ['required', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($user) {
        if (!\Hash::check($value, $user->password)) {
            return $fail(__('The current password is incorrect.'));
        }
    }],
]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#using-closures

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for this kind of solution only.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for this one!

Answer (score 16):

In Laravel 6 there is a new rule called `password` ,according to docs

> The field under validation must match the authenticated user's password. You may specify an authentication guard using the rule's first parameter:
>   'password' => 'password:api'

so the validation rules can be as simple as :

```
'current_password' => 'required|password',
'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
```

Comment: This the best answer i think for laravel 6. But note that `password` is for current login user not from model. This answer can be used for update password profile

Comment: Note: you have to use `current_password` instead of `password` as mentioned in laravel 8 documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-password

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by creating a custom validation rule (for this example I'm using `current_password` and `new_password` as the input names).

Put this in `AppServiceProvider::boot()`:

```
Validator::extend('current_password', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $user = User::find($parameters[0]);

    return $user && Hash::check($value, $user->password);
});
```

Now you can use the following in your controller:

```
$user = auth()->user(); // or pass an actual user here

$this->validate($request, [
    'current_password' => 'required_with:new_password|current_password,'.$user->id,
]);
```

Comment: Had to change it to `'required_with:new_password|current_password:'.$user->id` (colon instead of a comma), using Laravel 5.6

Answer (score 4):

Using **laravel 5.8/6.0**, here is what i do(without much additional code)

**Step 1: Validate**

```
    $data = request()->validate([
        'firstname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'lastname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'username' => ['bail', 'nullable', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'email' => ['bail', 'nullable', 'string', 'email:rfc,strict,dns,spoof,filter', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'new_password' => ['nullable', 'string', 'min:8'],
        'confirm_new_password' => ['nullable', 'required_with:new_password', 'same:new_password'],
        'current_password' => ['required', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if (!\Hash::check($value, Auth::user()->password)) {
                return $fail(__('The current password is incorrect.'));
            }
        }]
    ]);
```

**Step 2: If validation is passed**

1. Create array , checking each input value **(but not the ones with the required tag in validation)** for presence or null OR do something that you want.

For example:

```
if(request(input)){
    $data += ['input' => request(input)];
}
```

2. Update database using the created array

For example:

```
Auth::user()->account->update($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Validation rules for laravel 8.*

Default

```
'current_password' => 'required|current_password',
'password' => 'required|min:8|confirmed',
```

Custom

```
php artisan make:rule MatchOldPassword

//inside MatchOldPassword
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
   return Hash::check($value, auth()->user()->password);
}
```

```
'current_password' => ['required', new MatchOldPassword()],
'password' => 'required|min:8|confirmed',
```

Answer (score 1):

Validation rules for Laravel 8.*

use default available validation rules:

```
[
   'current_password' => ['required', 'string', 'current_password'],
   'password'         => ['required', 'string', 'min:4', 'confirmed']
]
```

- current_password based on [Laravel Document](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-current-password) check parameter to be equaled to authenticated user password
- confirmed based on [Laravel
  Document](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-confirmed) check parameter to equaled with new parameter named:

  {parameter}_confirmation

Comment: The english in this answer is difficult to make sense of. May need to reword it so it is more comprehensible to other readers.

Answer (score 0):

A complete function which will check everything. You just need to send `old_password`, `new_password` and `confirm_password`.

```
public function changePassword(Request $request) {
            try {
                $valid = validator($request->only('old_password', 'new_password', 'confirm_password'), [
                    'old_password' => 'required|string|min:6',
                    'new_password' => 'required|string|min:6|different:old_password',
                    'confirm_password' => 'required_with:new_password|same:new_password|string|min:6',
                        ], [
                    'confirm_password.required_with' => 'Confirm password is required.'
                ]);

                if ($valid->fails()) {
                    return response()->json([
                                'errors' => $valid->errors(),
                                'message' => 'Faild to update password.',
                                'status' => false
                                    ], 200);
                }
    //            Hash::check("param1", "param2")
    //            param1 - user password that has been entered on the form
    //            param2 - old password hash stored in database
                if (Hash::check($request->get('old_password'), Auth::user()->password)) {
                    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
                    $user->password = (new BcryptHasher)->make($request->get('new_password'));
                    if ($user->save()) {
                        return response()->json([
                                    'data' => [],
                                    'message' => 'Your password has been updated',
                                    'status' => true
                                        ], 200);
                    }
                } else {
                    return response()->json([
                                'errors' => [],
                                'message' => 'Wrong password entered.',
                                'status' => false
                                    ], 200);
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return response()->json([
                            'errors' => $e->getMessage(),
                            'message' => 'Please try again',
                            'status' => false
                                ], 200);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add `confirmed` as it's to confirm old password.
And `'required|confirmed'` you change to `'required|same:password'` to compare `password` and `password confirmation`

```
 'old_password'          => 'required|confirmed',
 'password'              => 'required|min:4',
 'password_confirmation' => 'required|same:password'
```

Good luck!

Comment: The confirmed under validation must have a matching field of foo_confirmation. For example, if the field under validation is password, a matching password_confirmation field must be present in the input.

Comment: This is wrong according to the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-confirmed

Comment: `confirmed` should be added to `password` not `old_password` field and after that there is no need to add `same` attribute in `password_confirmation` because it will match using `confirmed` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

In `Laravel 8.x` you can use this method in `UserController.php`:

```
public function ChangePasswordStore(Request $request, $user_id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($user_id);
    $request->validate([
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|string|min:8',
        'current_password' => ['required', function ($attr, $password, $validation) use ($user) {
            if (!\Hash::check($password, $user->password)) {
                return $validation(__('The current password is incorrect.'));
            }
        }],
    ]);

    User::where('id', $user_id)->update([
        'password' => Hash::make($request->input('password')),
    ]);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

In `web.php`:

```
Route::post('/user/{user_id}/changepassword', [
    App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UserController::class, 
    'changepasswordStore'
])->name('users.changepassword.store');
```